# Mysql Join Help

Tags: mysql, join

Ok.. I have 2 tables: **test_scores** and **test_exemptions**.

I need Select the test_scoreid to show only the test items that are NOT exempted.

Relevant Fields:

**test_scores**

```
test_scoreid    test_score_sid    test_score_testitemid
```

**exemptions**

```
testexemptionid    exemption_sid    exemption_testitemid
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as this has been driving me nuts.

Comment: Which field(s) could have common data in both tables?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!! As you're new here, remember to (vote and) [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) you think is the best to solve  your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that two tables are *joined* with fields **test_score_testitemid** and **exemption_testitemid**.
Try this:

```
SELECT ts.test_scoreid, te.testexemptionid
FROM test_scores ts LEFT JOIN exemptions te
ON ts.test_score_testitemid = te.exemption_testitemid
WHERE te.testexemptionid IS NULL
```

or

```
SELECT ts.test_scoreid
FROM test_scores ts
WHERE ts.test_score_testitemid NOT IN
(SELECT DISTINCT exemption_testitemid FROM exemptions)
```